# Code generation from java source files

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, code-generation

I'm currently working on a Java/Flex project and I'm looking for a way to generate some parts of my Actionscript code from my Java files.

One of the goal is to generate the AS valueObjects from the JAVA transferObject as well as some AS code to access the serverside function asynchronous.

And other important point is that I want to be independent of some IDE. The code generation should run from Maven or Ant and take the Java source code as input.

I looked a little bit around and found stuff like SpringROO, Groovy-GRAM, AST in eclipse,.. The guys from graniteDS do their code generation more or less the way I want to do it.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: If you've looked around, did you look into this as well? http://code.google.com/p/j2as3/

Comment: No, but this small tool don't really help me, because I don't have any control over the used templates. For example if I "convert" transferObjects, I need the "RemoteClass(alias="com.example.MyClass")]" meta tag to be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use now xText:

I created my one meta-model (grammar) from which I generate an eclipse editor plug-in.  This plug-in helps me to create the textual model.

From the concrete model, I generate with xpand and xtend the Java and Actionscript code

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/) for command-line AS compiling.. It's an open-source command-line actionscript compiler. It produces swf files which can be loaded by your AS code.

**Update:**

For Java to AS compilation use [J2AS](http://osflash.org/j2as).

Comment: Sorry, bit I don't understand how a compiler helps me to generate AS source files from Java source files

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated the post with correct reference.

Comment: I try to download, but I get a server not found error [http://svn1.cvsdude.com/osflash/j2as/org.j2as.build/deploy]

Answer (score 0):

Because you want an independent generator, [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com) could be an option. It's a standalone tool with no other dependencies. It does not have a command-line option (it's IDE-like).

It's great if you want to build your own code generator using templates, but if you want a already-made generator then you're out of luck...

Answer (score 0):

look at flexmojos project https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Home
it's a maven plugin for flex, you can specify a "generate" target and maven generates your vo from java files. https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Generator+Mojo

Answer (score 0):

GraniteDS GAS3 is a good one for generating ActionScript code for vaule object. 
The code generation can be customized using the groovy template.

http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/3.+Gas3+Template+Language

It integrates nicely with Eclipse IDE and also has ant and maven plugins

Answer (score 0):

We use our web service xsds that define the types to auto generate our java transfer objects as well as our actionscript value objects using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).  Hope this helps.